# Mybatis return large result with xml configuration in spring

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I need to dump data from a table in oracle to elasticsearch(100 Million record),
My memory limit of JVM is 256M, I use the following code and config to get the data from oracle (mybatis + spring):
the interface:

```
package com.fudy.mapper;
import java.util.List;
import com.fudy.domain.Person;
public interface PersonMapper {
    List<Person> selectAllPerson();
}
```

the xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.fudy.mapper.PersonMapper">
    <resultMap type="com.fudy.domain.Person" id="PersonAlias">
        <id column="ID" property="id" />
        <result column="NAME" property="name" />
    </resultMap>
    <select id="selectAllPerson" fetchSize="10000" resultMap="PersonAlias">
        SELECT * FROM person
    </select>
</mapper>
```

ApplicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="URL" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
    </bean>



    <!-- define the SqlSessionFactory, notice that configLocation is not needed 
        when you use MapperFactoryBean -->
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:Configuration.xml" />  

    </bean>

    <!-- scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.fudy.mapper" />
        <!-- optional unless there are multiple session factories defined -->
        <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

My junit test:

```
package com.fudy.mapper;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.fudy.domain.Person;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/ApplicationContext.xml"})
public class PersonMapperTest {
    @Autowired
    private PersonMapper mapper;
    @Test
    public void testSelectAllPerson() {
        List<Person> list = mapper.selectAllPerson();
        for ( Person person : list) {
            System.out.println(person.getId());
            System.out.println(person.getName());
            //TODO insert into elasticsearch 
        }
    }
}
```

you can see from the junit test, Mybatis will return the whole list of the result and this will cause out of memory issue. After google it, I find the ResultHandler may solve the problem, But I can't find a working demo.

Comment: I would say don't use mybatis, but plain JDBC and simply stream the results to elastic search instead of doing everything at once. Will be much more memory efficient and probably faster as well.

Comment: I know mybatis can do it, but I don't know how, I prefer to use Mybatis + Spring, it seems more maintainable

Comment: For this I would say it only adds complexity and loss of performance due to (possible) unnecessary object creation (each record is turned into a `Person` is that really needed).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two options:

1. use `ResultHandler`
2. since 3.4.1 use [Cursor](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/org/apache/ibatis/cursor/Cursor.html)

### ResultHandler

That is how you can use custom `ResultHandler`:

PersonMapper.xml

```
<mapper namespace="com.fudy.mapper.PersonMapper">
  <resultMap type="com.fudy.domain.Person" id="PersonAlias">
    <id column="ID" property="id" />
    <result column="NAME" property="name" />
  </resultMap>
  <select id="selectAllPerson" resultMap="PersonAlias">
     SELECT * FROM person
  </select>
</mapper>
```

PersonMapper.java

```
public interface PersonMapper {
     void selectAllPersons(ResultHandler handler);
}
```

MyService.java

```
class PersonResultHandler implements ResultHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleResult(ResultContext context) { 
        Person person = (Person)context.getResultObject(); 
        // process person here
    }
};
PersonResultHandler handler = new PersonResultHandler();
PersonMapper personMapper = ...;
personMapper.selectAllPersons(handler);
```

### Cursor

Starting from mybatis 3.4.1 you can return [Cursor](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/org/apache/ibatis/cursor/Cursor.html) which is `Iterable` and can be used like this (under condition that result is ordered, see above `Cursor` API java doc for details):

PersonMapper.java

```
public interface PersonMapper {
     Cursor<Person> selectAllPersons();
}
```

MyService.java

```
PersonMapper personMapper = ...;
try (Cursor<Person> persons = personMapper.selectAllPersons()) {
   for (Person person : persons) {
      // process one person
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm just curious, I know MyBatis but not this functionality. How would this avoid it to load full resultSet ?

Comment: When you execute query via JDBC the number of records in result doesn't influence memory consumption as resultset is effectively iterator over database result. The problem is how you use values obtained from result set. In the case when you use mybatis  mapper directly and it returns List<SomeObject> for each record from the query result an object will be materialized in memory. If you use result set handler  for each row handleResult is invoked and if you do not store the object it will not take memory. If you will store it to list - result would be the same that's memory will be consumed.

Comment: Thank you @romankonoval . Great Info! I will change a few things in some applications that I have!! +1 for the answer and the explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

I can see that Roman Konoval gave you a good answer for your question but I what to add something.

I had a similar issue where I wanted to iterate through a table and not to get it as a one huge list. I chose a ResultHandler solution but I found some troubles.

Even if you use a ResultHandler it might not work as you expect. I might seem to work properly until you use a very large table.

I found that two things are important :

- a place where you put your transaction
- setting a fetchSize parameter

Until I set it properly MyBatis consumes memory and get whole table before it runs ResultHandler.
When I set it MyBatis doesn't consume memory and runs ResultHandler immediately.

I prepared four cases :

1. a transaction is not set in a proper place.
2. a transaction is set but not a fetchSize parameter.
3. a fetchSize parameter is set but no transaction.
4. a transaction and a fetchSize parameter is set.

The first three cases lead to "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" on my computer.
The last case runs ResultHandler immediately and it doesn't consume memory.

My examples use a postgres database and generate some pseudo-table but of course it might be any large table.
A table in my examples has 1_000_000 rows.

MyEntity.java:

```
public class MyEntity {
    private Long id;

    private String text;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyEntity{" + "id=" + id + ", text='" + text + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

MyMapper.java:

```
@Mapper
@Component
public interface MyMapper {
    void selectAll1(ResultHandler handler);

    void selectAll2(ResultHandler handler);
}
```

MyResultHandler.java:

```
class MyResultHandler implements ResultHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleResult(ResultContext context) {
        System.out.println((MyEntity) context.getResultObject());
    }
}
```

resources/application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/temp1
spring.datasource.username=user1
spring.datasource.password=user1
mybatis.config-location=classpath:mybatis-config.xml
```

resources/mybatis-config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="MyMapper.xml"/>
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

resources/MyMapper.xml :

```
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.example.mybatishugeselect.MyMapper">

    <select id="selectAll1" resultType="com.example.mybatishugeselect.MyEntity">
    SELECT generate_series(1,10000000) as id, 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' as text
    </select>

    <select id="selectAll2" fetchSize="1000" resultType="com.example.mybatishugeselect.MyEntity">
    SELECT generate_series(1,10000000) as id, 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' as text
    </select>

</mapper>
```

MybatisHugeSelectApplicationTests.java :

```
@SpringBootTest
class MybatisHugeSelectApplicationTests {

    /* no transaction , no fetchSize parameter */
    @Test
    void case1(@Autowired MyMapper mapper) {
        mapper.selectAll1(new MyResultHandler());
    }

    /* no fetchSize parameter */
    @Test
    @Transactional
    void case2(@Autowired MyMapper mapper) {
        mapper.selectAll1(new MyResultHandler());
    }

    /* no transaction */
    @Test
    void case3(@Autowired MyMapper mapper) {
        mapper.selectAll2(new MyResultHandler());
    }

    /* good */
    @Test
    @Transactional
    void case4(@Autowired MyMapper mapper) {
        mapper.selectAll2(new MyResultHandler());
    }
}
```

Only the last one ( case4 ) works properly.