# Fetching of large data using spring-boot mybatis xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, large-data

My project uses mybatis v3.5.6 (mybatis-spring-boot-starter: v2.1.4)
It is written in spring boot and uses Mybatis xml mapper concept for writing queries.

I referred to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32364142
and tried to implement "**Cursor**" technique as below, but exception is seen. Please help if i am missing anything.

No special config other than the usual @SpringBootApplication and application properties below.

Idea here is that select * from employees will be replaced by a query which takes long to run (5 mins or so) and has many rows (around a million).
The goal is to create a dump/csv file.
I dont want to use offset+limit option since it will run the query multiple times each time. Also, I cannot pull all the data in memory at one go.
So want a solution which can achieve the best of two:

1. Query once
2. Fetch data in chunks.

Please provide suggestions.

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root@123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

mybatis.type-aliases-package=com.example.demo.model
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath*:/mapper/**/*.xml
```

**EmployeeMapper.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.example.demo.dao.EmployeeDao">
    <resultMap id="employee" type="com.example.demo.model.EmployeeModel">
        <result property="id" column="id" javaType="java.lang.Long"/>
        <result property="firstName" column="first_name" javaType="java.lang.String"/>
        <result property="lastName" column="last_name" javaType="java.lang.String"/>
        <result property="emailAddress" column="email_address" javaType="java.lang.String"/>
    </resultMap>
        
    <select id="getEmployees" resultMap="employee">
        SELECT * FROM employee;
    </select>
</mapper>
```

**EmployeeDao.java:-**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeDao {

    Cursor<EmployeeModel> getEmployees();

}
```

**EmployeeServiceImpl.java:-**

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl {

public List<EmployeeModel> getEmpployees() {
        List<EmployeeModel> employeeList = new ArrayList<EmployeeModel>();
        Cursor<EmployeeModel> employeeCursor = employeeDao.getEmployees();
        Iterator<EmployeeModel> em = employeeCursor.iterator();
        while (em.hasNext()) {
            //do processing using em.next();
        }

        return employeeList;
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A Cursor is already closed.
    at org.apache.ibatis.cursor.defaults.DefaultCursor.iterator(DefaultCursor.java:100) ~[mybatis-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at com.example.demo.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.getEmpployees(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
```

Edit: Using @Transactional on getEmpployees() of EmployeeServiceImpl made it work!!

Comment: If you are going to put them into a list anyway what is the benefit? Your method `getEmployees` should be annotated with `@Transactional` to keep everything open.

Comment: Sorry, but my question doesnt seem to be clear.

Comment: It is, but using a cursor and then still stuff it in a list beats the purpose of a cursor all together. That and your method should be transactional, else ever data access operation will have its own transaction and resource management and it will close the connection after you call `getEmployees` on your dao (the service should be transactional.

Comment: Please see edit for my question i hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: Your goal is to preserve memory but you aren't preserving memory because you are still sticking everything into a list. So you aren't preserving anything. If you want to preserve write the csv directly and keep nothing in memory. Also increase the fetch-size of your JDBC connection (the default is 10 you might want to up that to about 500) which decreases the number of network roundtrips significantly reducing the overhead.

Comment: 1. Yes, I will not write to a list.. directly to csv. 2. Can you explain where have i declared the fetch size as 10 or rather where should i declare it as 500?

Comment: Cool thanks! @Transactional worked. need to check if it works in a thread or not

Comment: The fetch size is something to set on the statement, not sure how to do that with mybatis., should be somewhere in the documentation. The default fetch size is 10, if not set it will fetch 10 records, send it to your program, until processed, do another roundtrip for 10 etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @M.Deinum, found out about the fetchSize parameter!! <select id="getEmployees" resultMap="employee" fetchSize="1000">

Comment: Cursors remain open only inside the boundaries of a transaction. You need to read all the data before the transaction ends. Annotatiin your method with `@Transaction` will make sure all the code inside gets enclosed inside the transaction boundaries.

Comment: yes thanks.. this got resolved.